# HTTP POST variable being corrupted when retrieving through PHP and Apache2

Tags: php, javascript, ajax, apache, dhtmlx

Sorry if this comes across as a bit all over the place. I have an odd problem and I'm not totally sure of the cause (as I've not been able to reproduce it but I can see by the apache logs that it exists)

I have some code that is failing because it is being passed incorrect data, the data is passed to the php script in javascript by an ajax call (using dhtmlxAjax.post)

sometimes, this data passed in the ajax call has been returned from another ajax call to the php backend.

Anyway, the end result is the data passed into PHP is incorrect. Sometimes I've seen that it has tried to post the entire web page content rather than an id for instance.

Which to me says that the data being put into the ajax post is wrong (or is it the $_POST variable is corrupt?)

I read somewhere that slow connections or certain browsers/ISPs? don't send content length in the header or something and apache can chunk up the requests, which could be a potential issue?

I don't know if I'm barking up the wrong tree though, so would really appreciate any pointers or tips on how to potentially debug this issue.

At the moment I can't get it to fail myself, but all I can see is the failed queries in the apache logs.

Thanks

---

**Update 1**

I don't think this is limited to the ajax calls. I've been looking through some of the other occasional errors and they are coming from form posts (via javascript using document.forms["myform"].submit(); )

So it's not going to be an ajax specific issue.

Could this be because of apache being overloaded with traffic or something like that and therefore garbling the POST variables?

**Update 2**

I've installed log4javascript and errorception (which I recommend highly! http://errorception.com/)

And I'm noticing the odd occasion that the URLs being called are becoming corrupted.

I'm noticing a lot of the GET variables in the URL string have this after them

```
¤t
```

E.g.

```
page.php?a=111&b=222¤t&c=333
```

Any ideas what that symbol means?

I've also had a few occasions of javascript files saying they can't be downloaded

```
The download of the specified resource has failed.
```

And a few instances of javascript errors saying ") Expected"

But the thing is the page never fails when I use it, and probably doesn't fail a lot as no users have moaned about any issues.

So I'm guessing it fails on a rare occasion and the user just refreshes the page.

But I want to get to the bottom of what is causing these random failures.

Is there anyway of logging apache to know if it has failed to return a page (or become overloaded?)

**Update 3**

Ok so I've noticed something about the random character in the URL

the param should say "currentClassification"

but its coming out as "¤tClassification"

so the url should be

```
page.php/param=1&currentClassification=2&third=3
```

but it's coming out as

```
page.php/param=1&¤tClassification=2&third=3
```

So how could this URL be corrupted? Apache, PHP or Javascript?

**Update 4**

Just a quick update, the line that is calling this url is in a php "Header" redirect.

e.g.

```
header("Location: page.php/param=1&currentClassification=2&third=3");
exit();
```

Would that make any difference to anything?

Comment: This sounds kind of vague. Can you make the php script dump a copy of the data it's sending/receiving and add it to the answer next to the data that your script is supposed to be sending?

Comment: Do you have more info about your problem? What is your query doing? Is the problem only in 1 location or does everything which uses ajax post failing every once in a while? Can you see what browser was used at the time of the failures? If so, is the problem browser specific or does it happen for all browsers?

Comment: @Shadur: I know it's vauge, it's because I don't really know what the issue is or what is causing it. There's no point in posting data as for example the code should be receiving an ID (e.g. 100) but instead it's receiving something else (e.g. SOMETEXT or even just the HTML document body). I don't know if it's corrupt at the point of the PHP getting it from POST or whether the ajax query is passing corrupt data. I can't recreate the issue myself.

Comment: @lljaas At the moment I don't have much more info than already posted. I'm doing some more investigation, but as I cant recreate the issue myself it's a waiting game for someone to trigger the problem. It doesn't seem to be everything that uses ajax, I've noticed it I think in 3 different calls (but that may be because the users that are creating the problem are only using a certain section of the system). Cant see the browser information, only get the IP address in the apache error log (which is actually the IP tied to lots of users)

Comment: That's why I'm suggestion you have the PHP script `var_dump()` the values as it gets them, and maybe do something similar at the javascript end.

Comment: @Shadur. Ok I'll add some code to capture stuff like this. It may be sometime before someone triggers the issue again! :)

Comment: try sanitizing all of your form data before submitting them on the URL in question